# Adding 2nd file extension to file with certain prefix

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

I have following files in bulk to modify `xxx.001`, `xxx.002` etc. by adding `.txt` at the end of the file name. In order to do this I am using following command:

```
rename XXXX*.* *?.txt
```

However it inserts `.txt` twice instead of once.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `?` from the target pattern? Take a look at the Super User thread [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874) which might provide a reason why (some of) your files become renamed more often than once...

Answer (score 0):

A solution is renaming the files matching a wildcard pattern using a **FOR** loop.

```
for %%I in (xxx*) do ren "%%I" "%%I.txt"
```

This **FOR** loop in a batch file searches in current directory for non-hidden files of which file name matches the wildcard pattern `xxx*`. Each file name matching the wildcard pattern is assigned to loop variable `I` without file path and without double quotes even on containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` requiring enclosing the file name in double quotes. The command **REN** renames the file by appending `.txt`.

The problem with this simple command line is that the list of file names in current directory changes while command **FOR** iterates over the list of file names matching the wildcard pattern. This command line could work nevertheless on an NTFS formatted storage media because of NTFS stores directory entries in a local specific alphabetic sort and the sort of the file names in current directory does not change because of just `.txt` is appended to some file names. But on FAT16, FAT32 or [exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) formatted storage medias this simple command line could fail to work as expected. Some files could be renamed more than once and others could be skipped because of directory entries on FAT drives are not stored sorted like on NTFS drives.

The solution is getting first the list of files to rename into memory and then rename one after the other. Then the list of file names does not change anymore during the loop iterations. This can be achieved with following command line:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "xxx*" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do ren "%%I" "%%I.txt"
```

**FOR** with option `/F` runs in this case in background one more command process started with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line appended specified between `'`. This means with Windows installed to `C:\Windows` that **FOR** executes in background:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "xxx*" /A-D /B 2>nul
```

Read the Microsoft article about [using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**DIR** executed by `cmd.exe` in background searches

- in current directory
- for file names of non-hidden and hidden files because of option `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- matching the wildcard pattern `xxx*`, i.e. any file name starting with `xxx`,
- and outputs in bare format just file name + file extension without file path never enclosed in `"` because of option `/B`.

The error message output by **DIR** if not finding any directory entry matching these criteria to handle **STDERR** is redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it.

The output by **DIR** (list of file names) to handle **STDOUT** of background command process is captured by **FOR** and processed line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself. This is the important difference to first command line. The list of file names is now completely in memory and **FOR** iterates over this list of file names not changing anymore during the loop iterations.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores empty lines which do not exist in captured list of file names.

**FOR** with option `/F` would split up each line into substrings using horizontal tab and normal space as string delimiters. This line splitting behavior is not wanted here in case of a file name contains one or more spaces. For that reason `delims=` is used at end of options argument string to define an empty list of delimiters which disables the line splitting behavior completely.

**FOR** with option `/F` would ignore the entire line if the first substring after line splitting (not done in this case) has a semicolon as first character. A file name can start with `;` and for that reason `eol=|` is used to define vertical bar as end of line character which no file can contain in its file name. So no file name is ever ignored by **FOR**. In this case with **DIR** outputting just file names starting with `xxx` the default `eol=;` could be used as well and therefore `eol=|` would not be necessary.

So **FOR** assigns one file name after the other output by **DIR** without path to loop variable `I` and runs the command **REN** to rename this file by appending `.txt`.

But there is one problem left if the current directory contains already files starting with `xxx` and having already file extension `.txt` because of these files would be also output by **DIR** and therefore processed by **FOR** resulting in appending one more `.txt`.

There are at least two solutions to avoid renaming files having already file extension `.txt`:

1. The output of command **DIR** is filtered with **FINDSTR** which outputs just all file names NOT ending with the case-insensitive and literally interpreted string `.txt` by using:

   ```
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "xxx*" /A-D /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /L /I /V /C:".txt"') do ren "%%I" "%%I.txt"
   ```
2. An additional **IF** condition is used comparing case-insensitive the file extension of current file name with the string `.txt` to determine if **REN** should be executed on current file by using:

   ```
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "xxx*" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do if /I not "%%~xI" == ".txt" ren "%%I" "%%I.txt"
   ```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`